# return a pointer in C, find value in string

Tags: c

I'm trying to learn C. I have a problem that asks me to loop through a string, find a value and return it.

```
int main(void)
{

    char *hello = "Hello";
    char *found_char = find_char(hello, 'e');
    printf("Found char: %s\n", found_char);
}

char *find_char(char *str, int c)
{
  int x;
  for (x = 0; str[x] != 0; x++){
    if (c == str[x]){
      return str[x];
    }
  }
}
```

and I get the following error

```
warning:returning 'char' from a function with return type 'char *' makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

I have a feeling I'm returning the wrong type, but I'm still a little fuzzy on how pointers work in C. Could anyone point out what I'm doing wrong, or what is going on this the pointer in the example problem?

Comment: What type are you returning? What type are you supposed to return?

Comment: Searches the input string `str` for the first instance of the 
    character `c` (an unsigned char). This function returns a pointer
    that points to the first instance of the character `c` in the
    input string `str`.

Comment: *returns a pointer that points to the first instance...* - Why do you think `str[x]` is a pointer? It is not.

Comment: Note, that even if you fix the function as suggested, it is going to print *the whole string* starting with the found character.

Comment: What exactly should `find_char` return: the found character or the **position** of that character in the string?

Comment: When you fix the problem in your question you'll also need to fix the problem of what to return when the value is not found. Your current code just falls off the end of the function with no `return` statement.

Answer (score 1):

`str[x]` is a `char` (specifically, it is an object of `char` type).

`&str[x]` is a pointer to `char`, also called a `char *`.

Your function is declared to return `char *`. So return a pointer to the `char`.

Comment: Please note that even with this fix the case when the character isn't found isn't handled properly.

Comment: Also, the OP's `printf` call needs fixing too.

Answer (score 0):

you need to return a pointer to the string you found

```
return str[x];
```

should be

```
 return &(str[x]);
```

Note that you function is identical to the standard `strchr` function http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strchr.3.html

Answer (score 0):

Learn and understand from what the error is. It says that ***your returning a char but your function is defined to return pointer to a char(char*)***

Instead of `return str[x];`, return a pointer to a char using `return &str[x];`.

Also there's a workaround.

You can declare your function as

`char find_char(){...}`

instead of

`char *find_char(){...}`.

Also change  your `printf()` statement.

Here's the changes i made:

```
   int main(void)
  {

     char *hello = "Hello";
     char found_char = find_char(hello, 'e');
     printf("Found char: %s\n", found_char);
  }

  char find_char(char *str, int c)
 {
    int x;
    for (x = 0; str[x] != 0; x++){
    if (c == str[x]){
       return str[x];
    }
  }
 }
```